# Bind to unknown property of div in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to switch the value of an attribute by binding it to a property in my component.

```html
<div class="app-container" [data-theme]="theme">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ThemeService } from './common/_services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  theme = 'dark';

  constructor(private themeService: ThemeService) {
    this.themeService.isDark.subscribe(x => {
      this.theme = x ? 'dark' : 'light';
    });
  }
}
```

By setting `dark` or `light` to the `data-theme` attribute, different colors are used.
So I just need a way of switching the value.

If I try using the code above, I get this:

> Error: src/app/app.component.html:1:28 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'data-theme' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Is there any way to bind easily my property to the template?
Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 9):

I just need to use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding), like so:

```
[attr.data-theme]="theme"
```